# how to adjust position of div

Tags: css, html, jsp

i have two divs search and demo. And div demo is

```
hidden {
  display: none
}
```

and **onClick** of button
i want to show div demo, whose content is loaded onClick event. Although div demo appears but on right of search div. i want it below search div.

Here is my code:

```
<div id= search>
    <div class="recruitment_input">
        <span style="margin-top:6px;">Search<sup>&nbsp;</sup>:</span> 
        <select id="requesttype" class="select_option">
            <option value="none">--Select Search--</option>
            <option value="design">Department</option>
            <option value="development">First Name</option>
            <option value="other">Employee ID</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<div id=demo></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p78Qq/548/)

Add style to your search div.
i.e.

Make `<div id='search'>`

as `<div id='search' style='float:left'>`

Then this will place your **demo** is apper right side of the search div

Comment: thnx for rply but i want demo div below search

Comment: m not using style='float:left' but still it comes left of search div

Comment: Please visit above posted JSFiddle in comment section

Comment: @Subodh Working fine?

Comment: no its not. on using firebug i come to know that demo div is placed over search div thats why demo div comes left of search

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35434/discussion-between-naveen-kumar-and-subodh)

Comment: Thanks man. somehow i did it. I used style='float:left' on demo :)

Answer (score 0):

**[EXAMPLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/8MNjL/)**

I believe this is what you are trying to accomplish.  `The $('#requesttype').on('change')` method could be replaced with a `$('button').on('click')` method as well.  Please let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

Modify with CSS?

```
<style type="text/css">
div#demo {
position: absolute;`
margin-left:50%;
left:-200px;
width:400px;
height: 400px;
background-color: green;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this what you are looking for:-

**HTML**

```
<button id="show">Show</button><br/><br/>
        <div id= search>
        <div class="recruitment_input">
        <span style="margin-top:6px;">Search<sup>&nbsp;</sup>:</span> 
        <select id="requesttype" class="select_option">
        <option value="none">--Select Search--</option>
        <option value="design">Department</option>
        <option value="development">First Name</option>
        <option value="other">Employee ID</option>
        </select>
        </div></div>
<div class="clear"></div><!--clear class will show your demo div down, even you have used any floating above-->
        <div id='demo'>your demo box</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#demo{display: none;}
.clear{clear:both;}
```

**Javascript:**

```
    $("#show").click(function(){
    document.getElementById("demo").style.display = "block";
});
```